# Javascript setInterval(), but clearInterval when the user/browser leaves the specific page (for single page app)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some functioning code (below) doing exactly what I want it to.  I'm just looking if there's native javascript/JQuery functionality which would take care of this already. Or if the 'if' statement/logic might fail to clearInterval for some scenario of URL/path/domain.

```
currentPage = location.pathname
fooInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (currentPage !== location.pathname) {
        clearInterval(fooInterval);
        return;
    }
    console.log('foo: ' + location.pathname);
    // other foo operations
},30000)
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Javascript stops running when you load another page so you should not need to clearInterval. Is this a single page app?

Comment: yes, single page app

Comment: then you probably deal with the history-object!? write a little wrapper that allows you to hook into all actions/methods you'd need. That way you don't have to poll for changes but get notified instead.

Comment: @Thomas, it's a Rails4/turbolink app (for single page scheme), so single page stuff is taken care of by the framework.  thanks, the wrapper of history-object looks like a good path forward